# C# WPF - Get mouse coordinates outside of WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I've made it so that when I hit CTRL+Capslock a WPF window shows. How would I retrieve mouse coordinates to be able to make the window pop up right next to the mouse no matter where my mouse is currently at.

So I hit CTRL+Capslock it retrieves cursor coordinates and positions window next to cursor and shows it at the same time.

I have been unable to find anything that actually works. - Thank you guys in advance. :)

```
private IntPtr HwndHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
            switch (msg)
            {
                case WM_HOTKEY:
                    switch (wParam.ToInt32())
                    {
                        case HOTKEY_ID:
                            int vkey = (((int)lParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
                            if (vkey == VK_CAPITAL)
                            {
                                
                                if (Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
                                {


                                    //Application.Current.MainWindow.Left = point
                                    //Application.Current.MainWindow.Top = 
                                    Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                                    
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                                }
                            }

                         
                            handled = true;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use P/Invoke, you can use [`GetCursorPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos):

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Point lpPoint);
```

Usage:

```cs
Point cursorCoords = new();
GetCursorPos(ref cursorCoords);
// cursorCoords now holds the screen coordinates of the cursor
```

...with Point being a sequentially laid out structure that contains an X and a Y coordinate. You can find such a structure in the `System.Drawing` namespace.

Comment: I was on vacation from work and came back to this solution. Thank you brother I got it working :D